# The size of the indicated variable or array appears to be changing with each loop iteration

Tags: matlab, matplotlib

I tried to plot the `Hx` and `Hy` for the following Matlab script but, I got the following :

`Undefined function or variable 'HxR'`

however, I have already defined it as `Hx=HxR+HxL` in my code. Matlab give the reason for this problem as(The size of the indicated variable or array appears to be changing with each loop iteration). Could anyone have any idea to help, I appreciate it

```
Ro=10.0;    % enclosing area radius
To=pi/3;    % angle between sheets
Uo=1.0;     
y= 1.0;
g = 10e-9;  % gap length  
Uo = 1.0;   
ro = 10.0;  
to = pi/3;  % Interior angle


m = 1;

for x = -g/2:g/100:g/2

SQP= sqrt((g+x).^2+y^2);


if ( x<= 0)

HxL = (4*Uo*(SQP/Ro).^(-To/(pi+To))*(Ro*y*SQP)*(-1+(SQP/Ro)^(2*pi/(pi+To))*cos(pi*(-     pi+atan(y/(x+g)))/(pi+To))+(g+x).*(1+(SQP./Ro)^(2*pi/(pi+To))*sin(pi*(-pi+atan(y./(x+g)))./(pi+To))))/(Ro*(pi+To)*(g+x).* sqrt((1+y^2)./(g+x)^2)*(1+(SQP./Ro)^(4*pi/(pi+To)))-2*(SQP./Ro)^(2*pi/(pi+To))*cos((2*pi^2 + 2*atan(y./(g+x))./(pi+To)))));
     HyL= -(4*Uo*(SQP./Ro).^(-To/(pi+To))*(Ro*(g+x).*SQP)*(-1+(SQP./Ro)^(2*pi/(pi+To))*cos(pi*(-pi+atan(y./(x+g)))/(pi+To))+ y*(1+(SQP./Ro)^(2*pi/(pi+To))*sin(pi*(pi-atan(y./(x+g)))/(pi+To))))/(Ro*(pi+To)*(g+x).* sqrt((1+y^2)./(g+x)^2)*(1+(SQP./Ro)^(4*pi/(pi+To)))-2*(SQP/Ro)^(2*pi/(pi+To))));

else

SQM= sqrt((-g+x).^2+y^2);

HxR = (4*Uo*(SQM/Ro).^(-1+(To/(pi+To)))*(y*(-1+(SQM./Ro)^(-2*pi/(-2*pi+To))*cos((pi*atan(y./(x-g))/(2*pi-To)))+(g-x)*(1+(SQM ./Ro)^(-2*pi./-2*(pi+To/2))*sin((pi*atan(y./(x-g)))/(2*pi-To)))))/(Ro*(2*pi-To).*(g-x).* sqrt((1+y^2)./(g-x)^2)* (1+(SQM/Ro)^(-4*pi/(-2*pi+To)))-2.*(SQM/Ro)^(-2*pi/(-2*pi+To))*cos((2*pi*atan(y./(-g+x))./(2*pi-To)))));
HyR= (4*Uo*(SQM./Ro).^(-1+(pi/(2*pi-To)))*((g-x).*(-1+(SQM./Ro)^(-2*pi/(-2*pi+To))*cos((pi*atan(y./(x-g))/(2*pi-To)))-y*(1+(SQM./Ro)^(-2*pi/-2*(pi+To/2))*sin((pi*atan(y./(x-g)))/(2*pi-To)))))/(Ro*(2*pi-To)*(g-x).* sqrt((1+y^2)./(g-x)^2)*(1+(SQM./Ro)^(-4*pi/(-2*pi+To)))-2*(SQM./Ro)^(-2*pi/(-2*pi+To))*cos((2*pi*atan(y./(-g+x))/(2*pi-
end

Hx(m) = HxR + HxL;
Hy(m) = HyR + HyL;

m = m+1;
end

x = -g/2:g/100:g/2;

figure
plot(x,Hx)
title('Hx')

figure
plot(y,Hy,'-r')
title('Hy')
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is just a warning telling you that if you preallocate space for your `Hx` and `Hy` variables (using `zeros` for example), your code will run faster.

The error is because you only define `HxR` and `HyR` in the `else` clause of your `if`, so it is very possible that when you call `Hx(m) = HxR + HxL;`, that you have not yet defined `HxR`. What do you want to happen for example on the very first run? There you will only have either an `HxR` or an `HxL` but NOT BOTH! So you should probably be initializing them to, so something like `HxR=0` before your loop begins.

But also watch out, on any given loop iteration, lets say `x` is less than zero, you will update `HxL` but you will then use your previous value for `HxR`. Is that the behaviour you are after?